# How to trigger a task in a different environment -- Rails 2.3/REE 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a weird question, is there a way in rails to trigger a task in a separate environment: Here is the scenario, I have a daily task that replicates all the data on production to a lower (demo) environment. At the end of this transfer I need to be able to reset the password for all users on the lower environment. Since I am initiating the task in production...I cant think of a way for demo to know when the replication is finished and start resetting passwords. I have thought about making it another time based task, that runs only in the demo environment a few minutes after the expected finish time of the replication task..but is there a smarter, prettier way of doing this?

Comment: How do you replicate the data? Do you dump the DB and re-import it? Is there maybe a way you can't export the passwords at all or automatically have them removed on the demo environment, e.g. with a trigger or something?

Comment: yes I am looking at a few different ways...but currently I am just doing a mysqldump and importing it in the staging environment. I am open to other suggestions though..if there is a cleaner way of resetting password in the other environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano), which allows you to define tasks/commands that are executed remotely, provided you have SSH access to the remote machine from the machine from which the task is executed. Ideally, a single Capistrano task would initiate the data replication and execute the password reset immediately afterwards.

Comment: hmm interesting I might look into it